# HAProxy redirect all HTTP URL to the same HTTP URL

Tags: haproxy

I would like to know if there is a catch all solution to just redirect any Incoming HTTP traffic from source URL to the same Destination URL via the same protocol HTTP.  Same with HTTPS -> HTTPS, *i.e.* https://foo.bar redirect to https://foo.bar

This must include all subdomains also ... *.foo.bar

2/21/2016 -- Update

I am running a 4 to 6 relay Proxy with v4 fallback.  The host will send an http or https request via IPv4, reaches haproxy server which then redirects to the same URL's IPv6 address invoking the "resolve-prefer ipv6" parameter.

I currently have this working for individual URL's but I want a catch all solution for host URL ANY use server {same as host URL}.

Here is a snippet of my current configuration for example:

```
frontend f_catchall_http
  bind 127.0.0.1:80
  bind 2001:19f0:4009:4083:5400:ff:fe1e:2a1f:80
  mode http
  option httplog
  capture request header Host len 50
  capture request header User-Agent len 150
  default_backend b_deadend_http

use_backend b_catchall_http if { hdr_dom(host) -i example.com }

backend b_catchall_http
  mode http
  option httplog
  option accept-invalid-http-response

  use-server example.com if { hdr_dom(host) -i example.com }
  server example.com hulu.com:80 check resolvers mydns resolve-prefer ipv6 inter 10s fastinter 2s downinter 2s fall 1800

frontend f_catchall_https
  bind 127.0.0.1:443
  bind 2001:19f0:4009:4083:5400:ff:fe1e:2a1f:443
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
  default_backend b_deadend_https

use_backend b_catchall_https if { req_ssl_sni -i example.com }

backend b_catchall_https
  mode tcp
  option tcplog

  use-server example.com if { req_ssl_sni -i example.com }
  server example.com example.com:443 check resolvers mydns resolve-prefer ipv6 inter 10s fastinter 2s downinter 2s fall 1800
```

Comment: Redirect via `3XX`? What's the use case? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What you are describing sounds like you want to generate a redirect loop?

Comment: How about you edit your original question to include the relevant information instead of posting an "answer" (which you call a comment) below?

Comment: Sorry .. first time poster.  Updated original post and deleted Answer.

Comment: I think I finally figured out what you're trying to ask -- it sounds like you are trying to use HAProxy as a *forward* proxy.  HAProxy is a *reverse* proxy.

Comment: Michael - Yes sort of a transparent proxy without defining and server directives.  There is a caveot however and that is the lack of DNS lookup.  If it does not perform DNS lookup then how does the proxy know where to forward to?  I read the documentation and found this parameter:

backend passthrough
    option http_proxy
    option httpclose